# Bash shell script: dynamically generating array variables

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I've found a few questions on Stackoverflow which are similar, but was unable to extract the necessary bash ninja, so I'm coming cap in hand for someone to clue me in. 
I'm using a bash script to download some currency quotes. The quotes are in a large text file and I use grep and cut to extract them. So far so good. All the quotes are against the USD. I download three files from current rates, one month ago and one year ago. 
Here is the code I came up with using 'declare' to set the variable names dynamically. This bit works fine.

```
for CURRENCY in GBP HKD EUR
do
    # Get rates against USD
    declare -A $CURRENCY
    TODAY=`grep $CURRENCY today.json | cut -f 2 -d: | tr -d "," | tr -d " "`
    MONTH=`grep $CURRENCY month.json | cut -f 2 -d: | tr -d "," | tr -d " "`
    YEAR=`grep $CURRENCY year.json | cut -f 2 -d: | tr -d "," | tr -d " "`
    declare ${CURRENCY}[USD]=$TODAY
    declare ${CURRENCY}[USD_M]=$MONTH
    declare ${CURRENCY}[USD_Y]=$YEAR
    # Get inverse rate
    declare ${CURRENCY}[USD_I]=`echo "scale=5; 1/$TODAY" | bc`
    declare ${CURRENCY}[USD_M_I]=`echo "scale=5; 1/$MONTH" | bc`
    declare ${CURRENCY}[USD_Y_I]=`echo "scale=5; 1/$YEAR" | bc`

done
```

So now, for each currency eg. GBP, I have an array with key - value pairs like this:

```
${GBP[USD]} = 0.65
${GBP[USD_M]} = 0.63
${GBP[USD_Y]} = 0.70 etc.
```

Right, so then I wanted to loop through each currency and generate the values of each currency against each other. i.e. get ${GBP[HKD]} ${GBP[EUR]} ${HKD[GBP]} ${HKD[EUR]} ${EUR[GBP]} ${EUR[HKD]}. This is where it started getting tricky.

I started another loop to attempt this, missing out the case when the currency was matched against itself (exchange rate =1). In order to get the first value, for eg, I want to divide ${GBP[USD]} by ${HKD[USD]}.

```
for CURRENCY in GPB HKD EUR
do
   for TARGETCURRENCY in GPB HKD EUR
    do 
    if [ "$TARGETCURRENCY" != "$CURRENCY" ]; then

    echo "declare $CURRENCY[$TARGETCURRENCY]=\`echo \${$CURRENCY[USD]}/\${$TARGETCURRENCY[USD]} | bc\`"
    fi  
         done
done
```

I can echo the command I want to perform in the above loop, but if I try to eval it, I get the message 'bad substitution'. 
I've been going over and over this, trying various things with eval and even other methods marked as verboten in other questions (so I won't fess up to them here). Can someone point me in the right direction? Using Bash 4.3 if that helps.

BONUS QUESTION. In my debugging, I've been trying to use echo ${!HKD[@]} to view the Key names. Despite everything written everywhere on the internet it doesn't work. Although  ${HKD[@]} does give me the values. Any ideas about this?

Comment: Sample output of that final echo statement is 

**declare HKD[GBP]=`echo ${HKD[USD]}/${GBP[USD]} | bc`**

Doing eval on that instead of echo doesn't seem to add the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `eval`; you just need indirect parameter expansion. Replace

```
declare $CURRENCY[$TARGETCURRENCY]=\`echo \${$CURRENCY[USD]}/\${$TARGETCURRENCY[USD]} | bc\`
```

with

```
numerator=$CURRENCY[USD]
denominator=$TARGETCURRENCY[USD]
declare "$CURRENCY[$TARGETCURRENCY]=$(bc <<< "${!numerator}/${!denominator}")"
```

(Despite the syntax coloring here, the double quotes inside the `$(...)` are distinct from the double quotes enclosing the entire argument to `declare`; the nesting works.)

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work as well, and also ... I learnt a new trick! Actually two: the <<< instead of the echo was a new one on me. 

So now just the mystery of why 
`echo ${!HKD[@]}`
doesn't list anything. Maybe I should put that in a different question.

Comment: Probably. It's not clear why that wouldn't work, since `HKD` is an associative array, regardless of how it was declared.

Answer (score 0):

Argh. OK, so in what is probably bad form, I'm answering my own question. Apparently I nearly had it, I just needed to tweak the echo/eval line. This one works
     `eval "declare $CURRENCY[${TARGETCURRENCY}]=\$(echo \${$CURRENCY[USD]}/\${$TARGETCURRENCY[USD]} | bc)"`
It seems part of the problem was that I was using the legacy backquotes form. Changing it to $() seemed to be the fix, although I changed a lot of other stuff too, so hard to tell when I got the magic formula.

OK, so that just leaves the question about why ${!HKD[@]} isn't working to list the key/index names.